# Emgu body measuring

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm developing a uniform fitting application, the program will take a picture of you and from that picture it will give you your polo/blouse size (Small, Medium, Large, X-Large)

My problem is how will I know if the user using the program has the size of Small? Medium? or Large?

here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.Util;

namespace fitting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        HaarCascade UpperBody = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml");
        HaarCascade LowerBody = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_lowerbody.xml");

        Capture camera;
        bool captureProcess = false;
        Image<Bgr, Byte> img;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void viewImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            img = camera.QueryFrame();
            if (img == null)
                return;
            CamImageBox.Image = img;
        }

        private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (captureProcess == true)
            {
                string data;

                Application.Idle -= viewImage;
                captureProcess = false;
                SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
                //dlg="Image|*.jpg;*png";
                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    img.ToBitmap().Save(dlg.FileName + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    data = dlg.FileName + ".jpg";
                }
                measureImage();
            }
        }

        void measureImage()
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg2 = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg2.Filter = "Image|*.jpg;*png";
            if (dlg2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = new Image<Bgr, byte>(dlg2.FileName);
                Image<Gray, Byte> Gray_Frame = frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
                //1.985603925968
                MCvAvgComp[][] LowerBodyDetect = Gray_Frame.DetectHaarCascade(
                    LowerBody,
                    1.985603925968,
                    0,
                    Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                    new Size());

                MCvAvgComp[][] UpperBodyDetect = Gray_Frame.DetectHaarCascade(
                    UpperBody,
                    1.3,
                    5,
                    Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                    new Size());


                //foreach (MCvAvgComp Upp_Body in UpperBodyDetect[0])
                //{

                //    frame.Draw(Upp_Body.rect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
                //    double width = (Upp_Body.rect.Width * 0.264583333);
                //    textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToString(width));
                //}
                try
                {
                    frame.Draw(UpperBodyDetect[0][0].rect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
                    double width = (UpperBodyDetect[0][0].rect.Width);
                    textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToString(width));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
                    //foreach (MCvAvgComp Low_Body in LowerBodyDetect[0])
                    //{
                    //    frame.Draw(Low_Body.rect, new Bgr(Color.Green), 2);
                    //}

                try
                {
                    frame.Draw(LowerBodyDetect[0][0].rect, new Bgr(Color.Green), 2);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
                CamImageBox.Image = frame;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool useCam = false;

            if (!useCam)
                measureImage();
            else {
                try
                {
                    camera = new Capture();
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
                    return;
                }
                Application.Idle += viewImage;
                captureProcess = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that your users can have various angle of views with different webcams.

Second problem is that you have to estimate the distance from user to his webcam because the more distant he is the smaller will be any dimension you measure.

I think you need to measure waist diameter etc... Is it ok or moral to ask user to take 2 photos? One directly facing the camera and one from profile. From this you could estimate the values...

So search for camera distance estimation algorithm.

After you have all sizes measured you can select proper size (small, medium...) from a table, see for example [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_standard_clothing_size)